# Using Ruby and Sinatra, Is it possible to use HAML in an "internal" or "inline" manner?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I've done `gem install sinatra` and `gem install haml`

And I have  this .rb file

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/abc2' do
"<b>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</b>"
end
```

Now say I want that line of HTML but in HAML. and not externally

I know I can do

```
get '/abc' do
  haml :index  # /views/index.haml 
end
```

And index.haml could have a line of haml  `%b aaaaaaa`

But is there any way that I can include `%b aaaaaaa` in my ruby file itself and have it rendered.  Without having to refer to a file e.g. without having to refer to /views/index.haml ?

Like CSS lets you have the CSS External, or it lets you have it internal within the html file..  Similarly, Javascript lets you import javascript externally, or it lets you have it internal to the html file..  Well i'm asking about using HAML internally to the .rb file.  Is it possible?

I know HAML is intended as a template language for injecting data into.. but it is also a shorthand for writing HTML more concisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Haml::Engine#render`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/haml/4.0.1/Haml/Engine#render-instance_method) to convert the Haml to HTML like so:

```
get '/abc2' do
  Haml::Engine.new(<<-Haml).render(binding)
    %b aaaaaa
  Haml
end
```

This uses a heredoc (everything between the `<<-Haml` line and the closing `Haml`. `binding` is a special variable that basically refers to the current scope.

Comment: I get an error  trying that. NameError ...
uninitialized constant Haml   https://i.imgur.com/zoEseZF.png

Comment: @barlop you need to `require 'haml'` first

Answer (score 3):

For small apps you can add the views at the end of your script so there are no external files.

```
get '/abc' do
  haml :hello
end
__END__
@@ hello
%h1= "Hello there"
```